# Core Data insert

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I try to learn Core Data and after many hours and a lot of tutorials, I am still confused. All the tutorials seem so complicated with so many elements involved. It would be very helpful if someone could give me an example of the most simple insert possible. (please without tables, navigation controllers... just insert a name and password)

I have created an entity of users with the attribute name and password
I have two textfields: name and password. I have the connection from the storyboard to the ViewController
I have a button

How can I save names and passwords when the user clicks to button?

```
@IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do you have an `NSManagedObjectContext` available at this point? Assuming you do and it's called `context`

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if let viewController = window?.rootViewController as? ViewController {
            viewController.context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        }

        return true
    }

    // ... other functions
}
```

```
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        assert(context != nil)
    }

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {

        guard name.hasText || password.hasText else { return }

        let newUser = User(context: context)

        if let nameString = name.text {
            newUser.name = nameString
        }

        if let passwordString = password.text {
            newUser.password = passwordString
        }

        context.insert(newUser)
        saveContext()
    }

    func saveContext() {
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have in the viewDidLoad:   let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate   
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

Comment: It seems it does not fit with your code. What is wrong?

Comment: are you sure that the @IBAction is linked to the button? That is being trigged on a press?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the links

Comment: It gives me that error: Cannot use instance member 'appDelegate' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: Where should the let appDelegate and let context go?

Comment: You make a variable in your base controller, and in your `AppDelegate` you set that variable in `application(_: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`. I will update my answer to show, using default Controller names

Comment: Every time I am more confused! I just give up

Comment: Don't give up!!

Comment: @segon heres a Git repo that has the whole project doing what you want https://github.com/mmr118/SegonCoreData, let me know if you want more examples of fetching saved data

Answer (score 1):

Very simple example.

Instantiate the context lazily in the view controller

```
lazy var context : NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}()
```

If it's going to be used only the in `IBAction` instantiate it temporarily in there (see commented out code)

Then in the IBAction write

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard name.hasText, !name.text!.first!.isWhitespace,
        password.hasText, !password.text!.first!.isWhitespace else {
        // show an alert that both text fields must not be empty and must not start with a whitespace characters.
        return 
    }
    // let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    // let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let user = User(context: context)
    user.name = self.name.text!
    user.password = self.password.text!
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Side note: To avoid ambiguity name the text fields more distinct for example

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
```

Comment: Is there any place where I can check what is saved? (I came from MySql and there is a table where I see what I have saved and clean if necessary)

Comment: Add `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` in the Run scheme > Arguments Passed On Launch. It logs the sql access.

Comment: I like your way to check if the textField has text: guard... But it has the limitation that if the user enters an empty space, it also is considered as hasText (but you see nothing and it would be better to return). Do you know any way to solve that limitation?

Comment: I added a check that both text fields must not contain any whitespace character.

Comment: Thank you. But I think that your solution will make return if there is any space. Also if there are letters and spaces (like between first name and second name.)

Comment: Now the first character must not be a whitespace character.